# Android HTTPRequest Cycle

Tags: android, json, httpclient, http-post

I am trying to send JSON to my server and retrieve a JSON in return as a result.
Like sending in username and password and getting back token and other content.

This is what i am doing for the HTTP Request for sending. How do i now retrieve back the content in the same request ?

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/temp/test.php");

        List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", jsonStr));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);

        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse res = client.execute(request);

        String[] status_String=res.getStatusLine().toString().trim().split(" ");
        //String hd=res.getFirstHeader("result").toString();

        //System.out.println("Res=" + res);
        Log.e("tag", ""+res.toString());
        if(status_String[1].equals("200")){
            isDataSent=true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add more in vvieux's answer:

```
res.getEntity().getContent()
```

will return you InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

```
String returnData = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HttpEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html)

```
res.getEntity().getContent()
```